# How to make CSS Grid Fill all available spaces depending on screen size without using media queries

Tags: css

Please note:
The use of 200px is simply to illustrate what I am attempted to accomplish.

Assuming I have 6 grid items, how do I make these these items symmetrically take up all horizontal and vertical space of a view-port? I need the items to resize regardless of how many are there but they should all fit the screen with out any spaces.

So instead of the top image, look like the bottom.

[image]

[image]
Regardless of the number of items, they will always take up all of the space on the screen.

Here is a sample code of what I am trying to do:

```
<ul id="content-grid">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#content-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

ul#content-grid li {
    background-color: bisque;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: This might be better handled with flexbox layout.

Comment: What's wrong with media queries? Css-grid is not a magic method for responsiveness its just another tool in the box.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with Media queries, I am just looking for possibilities.